# How to unit test sails built in model methods?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, sinon, waterline

I have a model named User in sails.
Lets pretend I have the following controller:

```
module.exports = {

    register: async function(req, res) {

        var record = await User.create({
            username: 'kevin chuka'
        });

    }

};
```

I want to stub User.create() in order to return true in the test.
**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  lifting sails before the test isn't an option, because in that case it wouldn't be an unit test plus when lifting sails, it messes up with most of the other unit tests I've written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`controller.js`:

```js
const User = require('./user');

module.exports = {
  register: async function(req, res) {
    var record = await User.create({
      username: 'kevin chuka',
    });
    return record;
  },
};
```

`user.js`:

```js
class User {
  static async create() {
    return 'real user';
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

`controller.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const User = require('./user');
const controller = require('./controller');
const { expect } = require('chai');
describe('60220190', () => {
  it('should create and return user', async () => {
    sinon.stub(User, 'create').resolves(true);
    const actual = await controller.register();
    expect(actual).to.be.eq(true);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(User.create, { username: 'kevin chuka' });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 60220190
    ✓ should create and return user


  1 passing (29ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |   83.33 |                   
 controller.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 user.js       |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```